# using has_secure_password and oauth (such as facebook) authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I am interested in using both of these authentication schemes but setting the user model to `has_secure_password` forces a validation on `password_digest`. I am curious if there is a standarized way for creating a user via an oauth mechanism in this way for rails 3.1.x with omniauth-facebook. Like stubbing in a `test` value into the password_digest or some other thing? Or perhaps turning off the validations in a certain condition when used with has_secure_password (although I don't know really how I would do this and would appreciate help).

I see that there is a commit for oauthed_user (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/test/models/oauthed_user.rb) but am not really sure about how this should be used.

thx for any info / advice

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know the standard way for doing this, but I did this in my app and it works perfectly

```
def create
  if user_is_from_omniauth?
    @user.password = SecureRandom.hex(9)
  end
  @user.save
end
```

And now you should sign in user without using password
For this its recommended to place a boolean in your database, so that it should not ask for old password in case of change password or forget your password